# Regex pattern matching behavior for basic implementation

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to count the number of syllables in a given word using regex. I've referred to some other posts on stack overflow but am getting strange behavior when I run my program.

Here is what I'm attempting

```
int n=0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]+[^$e]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Harry");

while(m.find()) {
     n++;
}

System.out.println(n);
```

Now, it's printing out 1. But there is both an "a" and "y" within the string. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the String there are no more letters to match so remove the expression `[^$e]`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]+");
```

Although from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808342/regex-pattern-matching-behavior-for-basic-implementation#comment66908123_39808392) you seem to want to treat `e` as a special case. You could do

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aiouy]|(?!^)e(?<!$)");
```

Comment: The purpose of the [^$e] was to ignore any occurrences of "e" at the end of the String.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon if that is what you want to do, you should be using `[^e]$` instead of `[^$e]`. Also, `[aeiouy]+` creates groups of one or more vowels because of the `+` at the end. I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Intersting. When I use '[^e]$' then the value of 'n' comes out as zero. Yes I'm looking for groups of one or more vowels and then attempting to not count silent e's.

Comment: Possibly what you're really looking for is negative assertions. See the update